# Modifying syntax so as to grey out the non-source part of an org file

Tags: org-babel, syntax-highlighting

I thought a nice alternative to `(org-edit-special)` (which
becomes cumbersome with many small blocks), and to
tangling-and-untangling (which is incompatible with noweb
references), might be simply to switch to the source mode, so
that source indentation and highlighting would work.

```
    (defun org*-toggle ()
      (interactive)
      (if (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
          (funcall (org-src-get-lang-mode (car (org-babel-get-src-block-info))))
        (let ((org-startup-folded nil))
          (org-mode))))
```

But this would be even nicer if the non-source parts of the file
were either displayed in the shadow face or completely hidden.
How could one achieve that?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/larstvei/Focus)?